# images are not being displayed

Tags: c#, jquery

I have done the following jquery function which is supposed to change dynamically images. The problem is that it is doing nothing as if there is no jquery function. The jquery function is being totally ignored without even enter in the function.

The coding I used is the one below;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="stylesPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = 0;
    var images = [
        'child.jpg',
        'girl.gif',
        'sponsor.jpg'
    ];

    $('Image1').attr('src', 'Resources/ChildrenImages/' + images[0]);

    setInterval(change_image, 5000);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        index++;
        if (index >= images.length) index = 0;

        $('Image1').attr('src', 'Resources/ChildrenImages/' + images[index]);
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="198px" Width="225px"/>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Any suggestions to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're probably not selecting anything:

```
$('Image1')
```

should be

```
$('#Image1')
```

Please note also that there's a difference between the ID that you set and the rendered one (which is ClientID in ASP.net), so you should either use:

```
$('img[id$="Image1"]') //Select an image whose ID ends with 'Image1'
```

Or reference the ClientID property in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property of the Image to Static, and as per the other answer the JQuery Identifier should start with a #, #Image1.